# Golang: How to skip struct fields while reading from a buffer?

Tags: go, buffer

http://play.golang.org/p/RQXB-hCq_M

```
type Header struct {
    ByteField1 uint32    // 4 bytes
    ByteField2 [32]uint8 // 32 bytes
    ByteField3 [32]uint8 // 32 bytes
    SkipField1 []SomethingElse
}

func main() {
    var header Header
    headerBytes := make([]byte, 68)  // 4 + 32 + 32 == 68
    headerBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(headerBytes)
    err := binary.Read(headerBuf, binary.LittleEndian, &header)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(header)
}
```

I don't want to read from the buffer into the header struct in chunks. I want to read into the bytefield in one step but skip non byte fields. If you run the program in the given link (http://play.golang.org/p/RQXB-hCq_M) you will find that binary.Read to throw an error: binary.Read: invalid type []main.SomethingElse

Is there a way that I can skip this field?

Update:
Based on dommage's answer, I decided to embed the fields inside the struct instead like this
http://play.golang.org/p/i0xfmnPx4A

Comment: Do you know the size of `SkipField1`?

Comment: Unfortunately No. skipfield1 is a slice of struct of varying size

Comment: I think you could define a new struct consisting of pointers to the three fixed-length fields in your other struct, and `binary.Read` would read into that. (Haven't tested and short on time, so not sure enough to submit it as an answer.)

Comment: Oh, your HeaderBuf thing is nice, ++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cause a field to be skipped by prefixing it's name with _ (underscore).

**But**: `binary.Read()` requires all fields to have a known size. If `SkipField1` is of variable or unknown length then you have to leave it out of your struct.

You could then use `io.Reader.Read()` to manually skip over the skip field portion of your input and then call `binary.Read()` again.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on "io.Reader.Read() to manually skip over the skip field portion"

Comment: I was suggesting that if you just want to read the fixed header part, then skip the rest of the header, and then read the body, I would recommend using something like `func (b *Buffer) Read(p []byte)` or `func (b *Buffer) ReadBytes(delim byte)` to do so. (If you have an `io.Reader` as your data source then you will have to use `Read`. The `Buffer` methods though are more powerful.